# Issue with slice() method, arrays apparently sorted automatically but they didn't

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, indexing

Edit: problem fixed, the issue I had was a splice() property that caused my arrays to interact that way, they didn't automatically arrange.

I am trying to make a object oriented game, got a constructor class that creates as many custom enemies as you specify a loop pushes the constructed objects into an array and stores them there. Players get also stored in a server-side array (this is meant to be a multiplayer game, just didn't learn node yet, but I plan to do soon, so I want this code to be scalable).

The enemies get selected individually from the array's index and can interact with the player, it's fully functional aside from one trouble.

Some code example, the trouble comes when some enemies or players die.

```
class Enemy
{
    constructor(args)
    {
        this.target = player[0];///Default

        this.kill = function() {
            //kill logic
            enemy[1].splice(this.indexid,1);///Despawns
        };
    };
};

class Player
{
    constructor(args)
    {
        this.target = enemy[/*gets changed using a method*/]
        //method here, removed to simplify

        this.kill = function() {
            //kill logic
            player[0].splice(this.indexid,1);///Despawns
        };
    };
};
```

Don't bother about the indexid, it's a integer that gets assigned to each enemy matching their array index once they are spawned, so I can opperate.

I have been testing if the game logic was working in google chrome console, this is the part of the code where I get trouble, because when the enemy dies the array gets **automatically arranged** and another enemy occupy its place, causing the player to swap target. Minor issue, but when an **actual player** dies then the players occupying its very same array index will get targeted by the enemies and some unpredictable stuff may happen. Also the indexid stops matching the actual array index, since it's only set when the enemy gets spawned:s

Altho this array index ids are meant to be temporal, I don't want the browser to automatically arrange the indexes because this breaks all the code :(

Comment: That does not happen? The array only changes if *your code* does that? Yet you haven't shown that.

Comment: JS arrays are not automatically sorted, so I’m not sure what’s the problem you’re facing

Comment: In the question text you said *"the array gets automatically arranged and another enemy occupy its place"* which is correct (that's pretty much the whole point of `splice`). It does *not* **sort** the array, as the title suggests. You might want to edit to clarify your title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) changes the indices of the following items.

Why not use `undefined` or `null` as value for the array. This approach does not change the index and is easily implemented.

Comment: May I ask you a question? The game loop breaks when it tries to read a null value:
```
update.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'posW' of null
    at Object.npc (update.js:10)
    at Object.start (update.js:3)
    at <anonymous>:1:8
```
(console log)

Basically what the loops does is call a loop 2 times per second, that loop checks for every player for(let p of player) and for(let m of enemy) so it checks the distance between each players and any npc in that same map, to render them.

Comment: you need a check first, like `if (item === null) continue;` (if in a `for` loop) or so to prevent a processing of a not given object.